# Using a 2018 (iso9660) live USB to copy arbitrary files (extra partition)?

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

In the old days, when I made a USB live installer for Ubuntu, it used to be formatted with `fat32`, and so I could have copied arbitrary files (say, pictures) on it, and use the same USB thumbdrive to both install Ubuntu, and to copy these files.

Unfortunately, something changed in the meantime; so now, when I use `usb-creator-gtk` to "flash" an Ubuntu Live CD .iso image to a USB thumbdrive, the format is `iso9660`, which is read-only, so I cannot copy files to the thumbdrive anymore. What is worse, I cannot even shrink this partition and make a new `fat32` partition: this is what I get in `gparted` for the USB thumbdrive (on Ubuntu 18.04) ...:

[image: gparted-sdc]

... that is, "Resize/Move" (partition) is grayed out - after "flashing" it with either `mkusb` (with "Install (make a boot device)" -> and either "Cloning iso file, [compressed] image file or device" or "'Live only' or linux installer from iso file" options) -- or `usb-creator-gtk`. (and if I unmount `/dev/sdc1`, then neither `gparted` nor `gnome-disks` see any partitions here; `gnome-disks` simply says "No Media")

This irritates me to no end - because the damn unresizeable iso9660 partition takes up the ***entirety*** of the USB disk (here 3.71 GB), whereas the actual usage of files for the installer is but:

```
$ du -hs /media/Ubuntu-MATE\ 18.04.3\ LTS\ amd64/
1.9G    /media/Ubuntu-MATE 18.04.3 LTS amd64/
```

So, nearly 2GB goes to waste!! And I could have very well used that to copy my pictures!

Now, I'm aware that I can use `mkusb` to create a "Live Persistent" USB, in which case I get three partitions - one bootable with the Live CD, one for persistent storage, and one extra `fat` partition that can be used to copy files - the thing is, I do ***not*** want a persistent USB in this case, especially since when I run the Ubuntu installer in that case, it tells me that it wants to change two partitions: the partition on the hard drive, where I want to install Ubuntu - and some other partition, likely either the persistent or the exchange one, on the USB thumbdrive - and then I really do not feel confident in continuing the installation.

So, my question is - what other options do I have, to have a proper Live USB Ubuntu installer - and an extra partition for copying arbitrary files (without persistent storage)?

- I've tried `mkusb` and tried to drag the slider for persistent storage to 0% - unfortunately, the minimum is 1%.
- I've seen https://superuser.com/questions/1192620/how-to-shrink-resize-32gb-usb-flash-drive-with-2gb-partition-into-2gb-image-file which implies you can use `dd` with specific byte/sector count; but then, it turns out, `mkusb` uses this (when not making other partitions):

```
< "/media/mydisk/ubuntu-mate-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" pv -s 2003435520 | dd bs=4096  of=/dev/sdc
```

... so even if the progress monitor is set to 100% for 1.9GB - the end result (the iso9660 partition) ***still*** takes up the entire drive.

- I've seen [How to convert an usb iso9660 filesystem to ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018412/how-to-convert-an-usb-iso9660-filesystem-to-ext4) and the answer is:

> There's no Easy Way to do this. It will be less stressful to re-create your Kubuntu USB with "persistent storage".

... but as I said, I do ***not*** want persistent storage.

- I've seen [Can I format and use the "free space" to the right of my Bootable USB stick's partition table?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957375/can-i-format-and-use-the-free-space-to-the-right-of-my-bootable-usb-sticks-pa) where the the initial answer is:

> The only use for a SDC install nowadays is for making an installer drive.

... but I mean - why? Why throw away 2GB of space that I could have otherwise used? (and otherwise, the answer is "make persistent USB", but as I said, I do not want that)

- I've seen [Ubuntu live usb with extra storage partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809695/ubuntu-live-usb-with-extra-storage-partition) - recommends Windows software LiLi http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ - but it does not detect my thumbdrive under Wine, even when formatted as FAT32
- I've seem https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-create-bootable-usb-with-multiple-partitions-4175602849/ which recommends YUMI ( https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ ), but that is Windows software, and it does not detect my USB thumb drive on Ubuntu 18.04 under Wine.

So, are there any options left here, so I can have an extra partition on a Ubuntu Live USB stick, without persistent storage, so I can just copy files?

Comment: Mkusb will produce a flash drive with FAT32 boot partition, ISO 9660 OS partition an option for ext4 casper-rw persistence partition and a NTFS data partition that can be shared with Windows.

Comment: Thanks @C.S.Cameron - if there was a way to avoid the casper-rw persistence partition with mkusb, that would have been the solution I seek. I mean, I know I could probably delete that partition with gparted, but then I'm pretty sure I'd encounter some boot errors, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: There is no need for a casper-rw partition with mkusb, the only thing that tells an installation to look for a casper-rw persistence file is the word "persistent" in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Remove the "Persistent" and "Persistent to RAM" menuentries in grub to remove these options from the boot menu.